# Passing an argument to Python C API function call

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to call a python function from C++. However, I could not figure out how to pass an argument to python function call.

I have a python file named "arbName.py" and a c++ file named "main.cpp".

***arbName.py***

```
def someFunction(a):
    return a
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <Python.h>
int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    //add . to path
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

    PyObject* myModuleString = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"arbName");
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
    PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"someFunction");

    //couldn't figure out this part. 
    //How to declare a python variable and/or pass it to the python function.
    PyObject* args = PyUnicode_FromString("1");
    PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(myFunction, args);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I was able to do it by changing the last two lines with

```
PyObject* args = Py_BuildValue("(d)", 2.0);
PyObject *myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);
```

Comment: That is my first question here, so it would be very nice to have feedback too!

Comment: You mean to parse command line argument? It yes change `int main()` to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. And then in `argv` you have params.

Comment: I mean passing a variable to python function.

Comment: Seems like you've found the answer yourself!